# no display when remote Ubuntu 14.04 from windows

Tags: 14.04, remote-desktop, xrdp

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with xrdp. I followed everything described by the video and the post:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KY3V79t5tKA

http://www.ubuntututorials.com/remote-desktop-ubuntu-12-04-windows-7/

However, I can establish a connection yet there is no display. What I get is only a screen with random background. I'm wondering anyone got a similar problem. Is it because of the v14.04?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This fixed the issues for me. Found it further below in askubuntu.

http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=5305